# Make App Launch Activity not be visible in application manage after back is pressed

Tags: android

Basicly, i have 3 activities in my app. call them A,B and Login, A and B shows the user very sensitive data. a legit flow has the form of launch->Login->A->B->A->B...->A->quit what i really want is that if for some reason the app got to the background ( by pressing back or home or whatever ) while it was still on A, or on B, then no metter what way the app relaunches ( or traced in some way including by the long home press menu ) it would not show A or B content. he can see either the login page content, or nothing at all.

noHistory is almost what i was looking for, but isnt a good solution since i want to allow intuative navigation from A to B and back to A. so how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the ["clearTaskOnLaunch"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear) Activity attribute.

> When the value is "true", every time users start the task again, they
>   are brought to its root activity regardless of what they were last
>   doing in the task and regardless of whether they used the Back or Home
>   button to leave it.

Comment: on which activity do you just to put it?

Comment: I believe you would put it on your Login activity.  From the documentation:  "someone launches activity P from the home screen, and from there goes to activity Q. The user next presses Home, and then returns to activity P. Normally, the user would see activity Q, since that is what they were last doing in P's task. However, if P set this flag to "true", all of the activities on top of it (Q in this case) were removed when the user pressed Home and the task went to the background. So the user sees only P when returning to the task."

Answer (score 0):

try the following pseudo:

```
public A extends Activity
{
   boolean just_launched = true;

   void onPause()
   {
      just_launched = false;
   }

   void onResume()
   {
      if (!just_launched)
         finish();
   }
}
```